# Spring Security for RestServices using Java Configuration with MvcWebApplicationInitializers in mixed xml environment

Tags: java, spring

I have searched quite a bit on this forum and have not been able to find an answer to this question.

I need to protect my RestServices with Basic Authorization. My SecurityConfig class is shown below and loads correctly. The log statements are displayed when the application is loaded into Websphere

```
@EnableWebMvcSecurity
@Configuration
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    private static final Logger LOG = LoggerFactory
            .getLogger(WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter.class);

    @Autowired
    AppUserAuthService auas;

    @Autowired
    AuthenticationProviderImpl auai;


    @Autowired
    protected void configureGlobal(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {

    LOG.debug("getting into configureGlobal");
    LOG.debug(auas.toString());
    LOG.debug(auai.toString());
    auth
    .userDetailsService(auas)
    .and()
    .authenticationProvider(auai) ;
}

@Override
public void configure(HttpSecurity http) {


    LOG.debug("getting into configure");
    try {
        http.httpBasic().and()  
         .authorizeRequests().anyRequest().authenticated();
        http.csrf()
        .disable()
        .antMatcher("/service/**") ;
    } catch (Exception e) {
        throw new SecurityWrapperException("configure() blowing up when trying to match /service/**" ,e);
    }

  }
```

My REST calls do not get checked with basic authentication though because I have not been able to figure out how to hook it up to the Servlet Initializer.

The problem is that all of the below config class wiring is done in various ApplicationContext.xml files. Whereas it appears I need to override the methods below. My question is do I have to convert everything over to JavaConfiguration or can I reference the appropriate classes that the application context files are using... and if so, what are their names? 
So for instance I know there is some "RootConfig".class that the getRootConfigClasses method below needs

```
    `public class MvcWebApplicationInitializers   
    extends  
        AbstractAnnotationConfigDispatcherServletInitializer {`enter code here`

        @Override
        protected Class<?>[] getRootConfigClasses() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return new Class[] { SecurityConfig.class };
        }

        @Override
        protected Class<?>[] getServletConfigClasses() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected String[] getServletMappings() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return null;
        }`
```

I would like to return the correct classes that the ApplicationContext.xmls populate. Obviously returning null for these methods is not a good thing. Is it reasonable to mix the xml with JavaConfiguration in general?

Comment: As explained by Anadi Misra, there's no problem mixing java config and xml in spring. The way to do it depends on if you use a web.xml. Do you ?

Comment: Thanks for your response. I do use the web.xml file now, that's how I load in my ApplicationContext.xml's as well as set up my DispatchServlet and Spring MVC. What I'm trying to do is just register my SecurtiyConfig.class to additionally be used by the Servlet engine to enforce SpringSecurity on my Rest Services. It seems like MvcWebApplicationInitializers would work but I need to know what classes to use for the @Override methods. Alternatively if there was a way to list SecurityConfig in the web.xml in a way that associates it with the Servlet.

Comment: I can see that you log the initialization at debut level. If Spring security filter chain were active, it should give debug logs too. Do you see any of those logs when receiving requests ?

Answer (score 0):

From the documentation

> In a Servlet 3.0+ environment, you have the option of configuring the
>   Servlet container programmatically as an alternative or in combination
>   with a web.xml file. Below is an example of registering a
>   DispatcherServlet:

```
import org.springframework.web.WebApplicationInitializer;

public class MyWebApplicationInitializer implements WebApplicationInitializer {

    @Override
    public void onStartup(ServletContext container) {
        XmlWebApplicationContext appContext = new XmlWebApplicationContext();
        appContext.setConfigLocation("/WEB-INF/spring/dispatcher-config.xml");

        ServletRegistration.Dynamic registration = container.addServlet("dispatcher", new DispatcherServlet(appContext));
        registration.setLoadOnStartup(1);
        registration.addMapping("/");
    }

}
```

So you can still use xml dispatcher configuration IMO